# Is c:out and esapi.encodeForHTML redundant?

Tags: jsp, xss, owasp

I know that the JSTL tag  escapes HTML so that angle brackets, apostrophes, ampersands, double quotes, and special symbols are replaced with equivalent named character entities.

However, I'm told to use OWASP ESAPI libraries, using something like: `ESAPI.encoder().encodeForHTML( variable );`. I noticed some code mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21164915/esapi-implementation-for-spring-form-tags):

`<c:out value="<esapi:encodeForHTML>${variable}</esapi:encodeForHTML>"/>`

I would prefer to just use `<c:out>${variable}</c:out>` rather than `<% out.println(ESAPI.encoder().encodeForHTML( request.getParameter('paramName') ); %>` or the combination above. Is that combination redudant, i.e. is enough to just use `<c:out>...</c:cout>` notation to prefent XSS?

Comment: What happened when you tested it?

Comment: the results are the same between `<c:out value="${param['my.web.param']}"/>` and `<%out.print(ESAPI.encoder().encodeForHTML(request.getParameter("my.web.param")));%>`. I just want to know if the latter is more "secure" somehow.

Comment: The ESAPI encoder encodes more characters. In particular, forward slashes are escaped. This may not be necessary, but it errs on the side of caution. See: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/49852/owasp-escaping-recommendation-why